# Remove Laravel/Debugbar Routes

Tags: laravel

How can I remove the debugbar routes?

In my .env file I already included

> DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false
> APP_DEBUG=false

I also run the ff. commands

> php artisan optimize:clear
> php artisan config:clear

but nothing.

The debugbar won't show in screen but it has routes when I do php artisan route:list. Please help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot!
you can just disable the debugbar as you did. The routes are registered with the package, so the only way to remove them is to remove the package from your project.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `php artisan route:list` will show you the routes for API and Web.
It's not about debugging true or false. It's about the routes that were used in the application. If debug was true then it will show you the necessary configuration given in the `.env` file. At the same time, it will also show you the error messages including the variable name method and where the error occurs.